# Unit testing angular-ui router maximum callstack

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular-ui-router and I've been trying to do some unit testing for a basic authentication, its working fine until I hit a maximum call stack error.

I've narrowed the error down to the $state.go call in the app.run section.
I remove this and the test works. However it breaks my app

What can I do to resolve this? so I can test this section and make it work as well?
Why does this work normally but causes a test error?

Error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
 at Scope.$broadcast (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12876:15)
 at Object.transitionTo (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2584:24)
 at Object.go (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2454:21)
 at /Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/js/core.js:9:5889
 at Scope.$broadcast (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12874:28)
 at Object.transitionTo (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2584:24)
 at Object.go (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2454:21)
 at /Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/js/core.js:9:5889
 at Scope.$broadcast (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12874:28)
 at Object.transitionTo (/Users/paulrobinson/Workspace/contactCachePOC/dev/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2584:24)
```

Code:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    var access = routingConfig.roles;
    $stateProvider
        .state('start', {
            url         : '/',
            templateUrl : 'partials/decide.html',
            controller  : 'decideController',
            data: {
                access: access.anon
            }
        });
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AuthService', '$log', '$location',
function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, $log, $location) {

$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(toState.data.access)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.error = null;
        //STATE.GO is causing the error
        $state.go('start');
        //$location.path('/#/');
        return;

    }    
});
}]);

describe('Test as an anonymous user', function () {
var $templateCache, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $httpBackend,
AuthService,, $location;
var roles = {
    anon: { id: 0, value: 'Public'}, 
    user: { id: 1, value: 'User'}
};

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$templateCache_, _$state_, _$stateParams_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_,
    _AuthService_, _sessionService_, _$location_) {
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    $state = _$state_;
    $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    AuthService = _AuthService_;
    $location = _$location_;

    //Fake it and say we're not authorized.
    spyOn(AuthService, "isAuthorized").andCallFake(function (state){
        return false;
    });
}));


describe('View  page.', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        $state.go('start', { });
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    it('Should view page.', function () {
        expect($state.current.name).toEqual('start');
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum call stack exceeded suggests that something is happening recursively.  I'd guess that the state that you are going to "start" is also not authorised, so you get redirected to "start" again, and so on.

You need to make your AuthService.IsAuthorized return true at some point

Comment: You sir are correct, I put a console log just before $state.go to get the current state and the current state is empty always!  console.log(JSON.stringify($state)); LOG: '{"params":{},"current":{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true},"$current":{"self":{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true},"resolve":{},"url":{"segments":[""],"params":{},"source":"","sourcePath":"","sourceSearch":"","regexp":{},"prefix":""},"navigable":null,"params":{},"views":{},"ownParams":[],"path":[],"includes":{"":true},"locals":{"resolve":null,"globals":{"$stateParams":{}}}},"transition":null}'

Comment: Hmmm but if there is a loop then why can I still physically use the site and transition to other states without the browser constantly outputting log entries?

Comment: because in your real website your auth service is working correctly, but in your test you fake the authservice to always return false:

spyOn(AuthService, "isAuthorized").andCallFake(function (state){
        return false;
    })

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it appears to be a bug with ui-router.

Here is a solution
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/178#issuecomment-49156829

```
$state.go(toState.name, toParams, {notify: false}).then(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
});
```

The above code will deal with the problem without breaking the browser or unit tests.
Just beware of https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1348 when using this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go("main", {}, {notify:false});` for notify to `$stateChangeStart` event.

```
$state.go("main", {}, {notify:false});
```